# AngularJS convention for multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, convention

I was wondering if there are best practices for avoiding monolithic js files in AngularJS.

I would like to avoid having very large controllers.js/filters.js/services.js files. Instead, for the sake of manageability, I would like to have each controller/filter/service in its own file.

I would like to know, if there is a recommended convention for this approach as far as the directory structure and naming convention is concerned.

Also, what might be the best way to avoid adding a script tag in my app/index.html for each new file I create?

Comment: The second question would be to use require.js and bundle/minify on completion.

Comment: I answered this a while back, see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461242/angularjs-application-file-structure/17461438#17461438

Comment: In the end I ended up using a combination of the 2 articles highlighted in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461242/angularjs-application-file-structure

Comment: I really don't understand how this could be "opinion based"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check this app: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

It is good example to start with.

> Also, what might be the best way to avoid adding a script tag in my app/index.html for each new file I create?

It can be automated by [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) watcher for example. I use such a config for this task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    index: {
        files: ['app/js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: 'index:scripts'
    }
})

grunt.registerMultiTask('index', 'Create index.html',
        function() {        
            var files = grunt._watch_changed_files || grunt.file.expand(this.data);
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var scripts_str = '';
            var tpl = grunt.file.read('app/index.html.tmpl');


            files.forEach(function(file) {
                file = file.replace(/^app\//, '');
                scripts_str += '<script src="' + file + '?bust=' + now + '"></script>' + "\n";
            });   

            grunt.file.write('app/index.html', grunt.template.process(tpl, {
                data: {
                    scripts: scripts_str
                }
            }))
            console.log('File "index.html" created.');

        });
```

*index.html.tmpl*:

```
<html>
<body>
    ...
    <%=scripts%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few conventions out there and it doesn't really appear that any "best practice" has emerged yet.

That being said, the two conventions that I like put each controller/filter/service/etc in their own directory. As far as directory structure, for smaller projects I've seen a directory for each type of file. For large projects, I've seen a directory for each module with all controllers/filters/services for that module in that folder. This also forces you to split your app up into modules which is a nice side effect.