# How to structure large AngularJS applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, program-structure

I have a web app that I'm building in AngularJS.  It has accumulated 500 lines of code and is quite a burden to sort through it all.  I was wondering if it would be possible for me to break off the logic into multiple files but still be able to interact with some of the $scope variables.  Any resources on this topic would be appreciated.

Ex:  I have a bunch of logic dealing with tables generated by ng-repeat that doesn't need to interact with code from graphs that I'm generating using Canvas.JS

Comment: 500 lines of code globally doesn't sound that much for an AngularJS app..

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon it's hard for other people in my organization to "come on" and help me when there is a time crunch, plus I would like to implement best practices if practical.

Comment: I use separate folders for separate types of constructs, for example, i'll have one for each fo the following: directives, controllers, services, and scripts. scripts is used for externally included modules and for angular.js itself, the other three are self explanatory. Then, within each folder, i have a separate files for different parts of the application. I use grunt to concat/minify all of the files and publish to a build folder.

Comment: @SleepDeprivedBulbasaur I know, I didn't mean to be unpleasant.. but maybe if your (or your colleagues') code is messy after 500 lines, maybe you need to refactor / redesign the project structure first, which is your purpose If I got it right. The links in the answer below will surely help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These articles might help you:

- http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps
- http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript

Also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461242/angularjs-application-file-structure).

I mostly choose the [Modular approach](http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript#modularity).

Answer (score 0):

Did you code all your app in a single controller?

I would think about:

- Having an skinny controller (only exposing the scope content needed, and grabbing the content from services).
- Implement services (Factories), in this factories you can for instance encapsulate your $http request to get the data you want to show.
- Implement directives: e.g. if you are building a common chart, you can encapsulate it in a directive (it's like a control), is easier to maintain and reuse.

Once you have that I would jump into Danilo great suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it all in one controller.  

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another link that might help you:

- http://leog.me/log/large-angularjs-app-components

It's about a solution with RequireJS to partition the application in multiple modules that can be hooked together very easy.