# Structuring a NodeJS app using Angular and NodeJS Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ntvs

I would like to know how do you usually organize your application structure when building a NodeJS application using [nvst](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools). When I create my app it automatically build up this structure for me:
[image]

So, the first thing that came to my mind was, where should I put my controllers and how do I connect them with the routes and views?

Also, how can I organize my unit testing logic?

Answer (score 0):

An NTVS angular app is still just an angular app.  The advice in [AngularJS application file structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17461242/8155) applies.

Going further, General principle:  You should be able to find what you're looking for without excessive drilling or scrolling.

Schemes:

- for smaller apps, folder by type: controller; service; model
- for larger apps, folder by function: user; cart; search; grid

I lean toward folder by function, as it keeps files that may need to be modified at the same time together.

As for unit tests, I have seen either `myfile.test.js` or `myfile.spec.js` sitting right beside `myfile.js`.  If you do not include the test files in the index.js, then they won't be loaded and don't cause a problem.