# Best structure for starting an angular js app?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating a new angular js web app for a website, this will not be SPA.
I will use these libs ui-router, ui-bootstrap, ngResource, in starting.
so, can anyone help me by giving a suggestion on these questions.

1. which structure of files I need to follow?
2. any link of demo made with standard structure or jhon papa's style guide?
3. how to include states in ui-router dynamically.
4. way to add as minimum as possible files in head.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS application file structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461242/angularjs-application-file-structure)

Answer (score 0):

I see you like jhon papa's style guide, he created some demo for that. Here is the structure :

```
/build  (created on the fly)
/gulp   
/src
    /client
        /app
        /content
        /test
    /server
        /data
        /routes
```

reference: https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/tree/master/modular

For add minimum file (in this case is JS file or CSS), you can concat several  your js file into one file use gulp or webpack. With that, you can minified & uglified too.

Comment: i dont know about gulp or webpack, can you explain a little bit.

Comment: @RamanKumar gulp is a task runner that help you automate the boring process like concatenation of several js file to one file. However it require npm to install gulp. http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-task-runner-gulp